# ¿Cómo puedo centrar un label y un textarea?

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente pedazo de código, el cual forma parte de un formulario:

```html
<p>
  <label>Mensaje:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <textarea name="mensaje" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
</p>
```

El resultado de esto es que el `label` se ubica a la parte inferior del `textarea`. ¿Qué se puede hacer para que el label se ubique el parte de arriba?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si quieres poner el `<label>` en la parte superior puedes utilizar la propiedad de css `vertical-align: top;`

Te quedaría algo asi:

```css
label {
      vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>Mensaje:</label>&nbsp;&nbsp;
  <textarea name="mensaje" rows="10" cols="70"></textarea>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

Podes hacer lo que buscas utilizando **flexbox**. Basicamente es una forma de ordenar los elementos unidimensionalmente, asi por ejemplo, podes poner los elementos en forma de columna o en fila, y ordenarlos en cualquiera de esos dos layouts. Seria algo asi:

Teniendo:

```html
<!-- Cambie tu p por un div, que es mas apropiado -->
<div class="contenedor">
  <label>Mensaje: <.label>
  <textare name="mensaje" row="10" cols="70" />
</div>
```

Si queres que `label` quede encima del area de texto, los estilos serian:

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

Esto tambien podrias lograr simplemente agregando `display: block;` al elemento `label`, para que ocupe todo el espacio horizontal del que dispone.

Por el contrario, si lo que queres es que label quede a la derecha del input, a como esta ahorita, pero queres que esten alineados verticalmente:

```css
.contenedor {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Me avisas si te funciono y si era eso lo que buscabas.